# How to get the current courseid for the current page in moodle

Tags: moodle

i have an addres moodle/course/modedit.php?add=page&type=&course=4&section=1&return=0&sr=0  in moodle. How can i get the courseid that is 4? I tried $COURSE->id but it doesnot worked.
Please help me with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Could you show the code?

You could try

```
$courseid = $PAGE->course->id
```

or

```
$courseid  = optional_param('course', null, PARAM_INT);
```

Answer (score 2):

make sure that you are using global $COURSE firstly.

```
function getCourses(){
   global $COURSE;
   echo $COURSE->id;
}
```